# Parcelable Confusion

Tags: android, object, parcelable, serializable

I am newB in Android. I was working on a problem where I came across passing custom object between Activity. I did some research and found that, if I need to either implement Serializable or Parcellable interface, I also found that Parcellable is faster compared to Serializable. But I am having confusion on, let's say I have multiple custom Object in my class as property then do I need to make all those Object to implement either or those interface or there is any other method to do that.

Forgive me if I am not clear, please feel free to edit if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to use them would be to make your class implement `Serializable`, and make sure that every one of the class members also implement `Serializable` (or is a base value like int).

If you have a member that does not implement `Serializable`, you're going to have to implement the serialize/deserialize methods of our class manually.

`Parcelable` is more efficient, but not as automatic as `Serializable`.
Check out this blog on how to use `Parcelable`:
http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Comment: Thanks, @tbkn very useful link. Now I understood it properly.